# What are these re.search meta characters doing? Where is my address? Not fully understanding syntax and RB

Tags: python, arrays, python-re

```
my_address = re.search(rb'\x80\xC9.{4}\x94\x12\x8A\x41\x08', bytes).start() + 5
```

Read the doc but I'm a bit confused.

My guess is

```
\x80\xC9\BYTE\BYTE\BYTE\BYTE\BYTE\x94\x12\x8A\x41\x08\BYTE\BYTE\BYTE\BYTE\BYTE\my_address\
```

Thanks

Comment: Where did you conjure up the end of that? It simpdy matches `\x80\xC9\BYTE\BYTE\BYTE\BYTE\x94\x12\x8A\x41\x08` if by `\BYTE` you mean one arbitrary byte (other than newline).

Comment: Looks for `\x80\xC9` followed by any 4 unspecified bytes followed by `\x94\x12\x8A\x41\x08` and returns the offset of the last of the 4 unspecified bytes. It may then (who knows?) use the value of that byte as an offset to find string data elsewhere.

Comment: yeah arbitrary bytes. thanks, the end is the .start() + 5, what is it doing?

Comment: oh okay, I think its giving me

`\x80\xC9\BYTE\BYTE\my_address\x94\x12\x8A\x41\x08`

Comment: What do you mean by including ``my_adress`` in your guess?